# Why does std::map< std::map > not deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

In the following test program, the memory allocated by the `std::map` is not deallocated. All in all we allocate roughly 2.2 GB of memory, which is never released, although we do a swap with an empty container.

When changing the `std::map< std::map >` to become a `std::map< std::vector >`, the memory is actually released.

I have checked the code with valgrind, which obiously does not find any leaks.

Why is this the case, and how can I change the behavior?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class Test
{
   public:
   std::vector< std::pair< int, int > > myContainer;
   std::map<int,int> myMap;

   Test(){
      for( int i = 0 ; i  < 10000; i++  ){
         std::pair<int, int> pair = std::make_pair<int, int>( rand(), int( i ) );
         //myContainer.push_back( pair );
         myMap.insert( pair );
      }            
   }
};

int main()
{

  std::map<int,Test> myContainer1;

   for( int i = 0 ; i < 5000; i++  ){      
      myContainer1.insert( std::make_pair<int, Test>( rand(), Test() ) ); 
   }      

   std::cout << "ready!" << std::endl;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 5000 ) );
   std::cout << "cleaning..." << std::endl;

   {
      std::map<int,Test> tmp;
      myContainer1.swap( tmp );
   }

   std::cout << "cleaning ready!" << std::endl;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 15000 ) );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you determining the memory is not released?

Comment: I used a system monitor, resident memory size. When using the `map< vector >` I see that the process RSS goes down to a few MB. When using `map<map>`, RSS stays at 2 GB.

Comment: @bicu that doesn't necessarily mean the memory isn't getting released (although RSS *is* *usually* a better indicator than VSIZE). `valgrind` will usually report (amongst other things) how much memory is still allocated at the end of a program and is much more reliable than looking at resource monitor stats. What values are you seeing there?

Comment: Your assessment is most probably wrong! Which OS, and how are you determining it? Working sets, paged/non-paged, would make the difference.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Linux with gcc 4.9. However on OS X with LLVM clang 7.0.2, this is not reproducible. It seems to be runtime/OS specific. Question is: Are there runtime/OS functions to manually clean up the heap?

Comment: @Arne yes (`munmap` comes immediately to mind). It probably comes down to how the stdlib implementation (or the underlying libc) handles deallocations. It's also possible that the difference between vector (contiguous storage) and map (probably not) make a difference to how quickly/easily the various bits of memory are cleaned up and paged out.

Comment: Perhaps a custom allocator could be used here

Comment: Yes, I think some kind of custom block allocatir might solve the problem. Are there any standard ones? Boost...?

Answer (score 10):

the internal of `std::map` uses black/red tree to store objects, which contains many small object, but `std::vector` stores objects continuously, using a large flat memory block.

`glibc` maintains different type of memory differently.

When requesting small objects, usually memory pool is used to avoid external fragments, but will causing internal fragments when the object freed, and the internal fragments will never return to the system.

When requesting large blocks, glibc alloc a large memory block, which may contains external fragments. but when freed, the memory will return to the system.